# HIBERNATE - could not resolve property

Tags: hibernate

I use hibernate criteria, and I would like to compare the variable in my code. But I have still this problem :

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: isBike of: models.PolozkyEntity
```

In other part of my code it is working perfect but there, I do not know why, it is not working.

PolozkyEntity.class :

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "polozky", schema = "", catalog = "dbs_projekt")
public class PolozkyEntity {
    private int id;
    private int idProduct;
    private boolean isBike;
    private boolean isAccessories;
    private ObjednavkaEntity id_odbjednavkyByIdO;

    @Id  @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id")
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "id_product")
    public int getIdProduct() {
        return idProduct;
    }

    public void setIdProduct(int idProduct) {
        this.idProduct = idProduct;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "is_bike")
    public boolean isBike() {
        return isBike;
    }

    public void setBike(boolean isBike) {
        this.isBike = isBike;
    }

    @Basic
    @Column(name = "is_accessories")
    public boolean isAccessories() {
        return isAccessories;
    }

    public void setAccessories(boolean isAccessories) {
        this.isAccessories = isAccessories;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        PolozkyEntity that = (PolozkyEntity) o;

        if (id != that.id) return false;
        if (idProduct != that.idProduct) return false;
        if (isBike != that.isBike) return false;
        if (isAccessories != that.isAccessories) return false;
        if (id_odbjednavkyByIdO != that.id_odbjednavkyByIdO) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = id;
        result = 31 * result + idProduct;
        result = 31 * result + (isBike ? 1 : 0);
        result = 31 * result + (isAccessories ? 1 : 0);
        return result;
    }

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_objednavky", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    public ObjednavkaEntity getId_odbjednavkyByIdO() {
        return id_odbjednavkyByIdO;
    }

    public void setId_odbjednavkyByIdO(ObjednavkaEntity idObjednavky) {
        this.id_odbjednavkyByIdO = idObjednavky;
    }

}
```

next

when I make this :

```
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(PolozkyEntity.class);
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("id_odbjednavkyByIdO.id", find));
        criteria.add(Restrictions.like("isBike", "true"));
        list_pom = criteria.list();
```

The problem is on line

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("isBike", "true"));
```

Can you help me pls?

Comment: Try "bike" instead of "isBike".

Comment: @TomášČičman Because that's how the Java Bean spec defines properties. The property foo corresponds to the accessors getFoo() and setFoo(). For boolean properties, the getter can be isFoo().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as suggested in comment use `bike` instead of `isBike`. The reason for that is that Hibernate reaches class' properties through getters and setters. Thus, Hibernate knows that to access property e.g. `prop`, it must use accessor methods like `getProp()\isProp()` and `setProp(...)`, so the programmer can simply use names of the properties and doesn't have to think about accessor methods.

When You put `isBike` in your code, Hibernate was searching for method `getIsBike()` to access it, which it obviously couldn't find.